# VWD Express won't let me add one table

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, database

I really haven't found any related questions and I am shaking too much to think logically. I spent like few hours waiting for SQL Server to finally install (you know, it's Microsoft) and now when I want to add new table to database it says "this feature is not supported by Microsoft Visual Web Developer Express". How could this happen? I mean, what's the point of even letting me use this if I can't even add one table to database, and I won't even know about it until I actually need to do it? Are they really serious or is it just some mistake? Is there any way to get around this problem? I need to create just one simple project with one small table in database but it won't let me, but I can't believe they could actually have nerves to make express edition without such a trivial function, so maybe I just made something wrong and there's actually some way to add this table? Sorry for being so whiny but I'm just fed up with this environment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Database management is only included in the full versions of Visual Studio.

Instead, use SQL Server Management Studio (Express)

Comment: Thank you so much, and sorry for being such a crybaby.